# How do I see Exception details in SignalR when self hosted with OWIN

Tags: signalr, owin, self-hosting

I am currently receiving a 500 error message when trying to connect my .NET WPF application to a server running SignalR that is self hosted with OWIN. I have tried setting the EnableDetailedErrors to true in the hub configuration. I have also tried OnIncomingError in the HubPipelineModule. Neither have worked. Any other ideas on how I can see the specific error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [IAppBuilder.UseErrorPage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.errorpageextensions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) extension method to see exception details instead of a blank 500 response. This method is available via the [Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics/2.1.0) NuGet package.

Make sure you call `UseErrorPage` *before* calling `MapSignalR` or adding other middleware that may throw an exception.

More information on `UseErrorPage` can be found in the **Add OWIN Diagnostics** section of the following article: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana